# "If + would" conditional in present perfect tense

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

Is it allowed to use the "if + would" conditional when speculating about a polite request that could have taken place in past? I know that the would structure can be used to make a polite request, but can it be used for making one in the past as well?

> If he would have told me what he wanted for lunch, I would have cooked it for him.

Also, may I use this construction in the past perfect tense?

Example: If he "would had told" me what he wanted for lunch, I would have cooked it for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"will" and "would" can be used in conditional clauses when a polite request is implied (the examples are taken from [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv315.shtml)):

- If you **'ll** just fill in this form before you go, you can hand it in to reception.
- If you **would** take a seat, the doctor will see you in five minutes.

However, strictly speaking, this cannot be the case with a counterfactual conditional sentence in which both the condition and the result are set in the past.

In [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-if), we find this reference:

*We use would have + -ed in the main clause, not in the conditional clause:*

*If he had stayed in the same room as Dave, it would have been a disaster.*

***Not***: If he would have stayed … it would have been a disaster.

*People do sometimes use the form with "would have" in informal speaking, but many speakers consider it incorrect.*

Comment: +10 if I could. Not a native speaker, but I learnt that "would" can _never_ be in the part of sentence with "if", the only exception are polite requests. See [here](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/if.htm) and [here](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/will_would_if_clauses.htm). So I wonder what the currently accepted answer is about.

Comment: @rexkogitans It's safer not to use "would" -- only native speakers know how and when to use it in conditional clauses. You may want to read this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248905242_Tense_and_Time_in_Counterfactual_Conditionals by Renaat Declerck, an expert in English tenses and conditional sentences.

Comment: Well, point 32 of this paper is the only occurrence of "would" in the if-part. I admit, it is hard to recognise as such.

Comment: "would" is accepted by some speakers when it has a volitional sense. Thus, "if he would have told me" is similar to "if he had wanted to tell me".

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this:

> ✔ If he **would** ***have*** told me what he wanted for lunch, I would have cooked it for him.

However, it's a bit more common for it to be phrased this way:

> ✔  If he ***had*** told me what he wanted for lunch, I would have cooked it for him.

---

On the other hand, the combination of both *would* and *had* does ***not*** work:

> ✘ If he **would** ***had*** told me what he wanted for lunch, I would have cooked it for him.

Comment: But what about the construction: "If Robert wasn't so lazy he could have been promoted."  And also: "If Robert wasn't so lazy he will be promoted." Are the tenses in the second clause interchangeable? Is it allowed to use them in this form?

Comment: Idiomatically, your first sentence is fine. Technically speaking (according to traditional grammar) it should be *If Robert **weren't** so lazy he could have been promoted.* Your second sentence should be rephrased: *Robert **would** be promoted if he **weren't** so lazy.*

Comment: In Australian grammar, we never say "If he **were**", always "If he **was**" for the subjunctive. See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be#Conjugation Unfortunately, that implies that Australian English is "non-standard". Note that some other English variants use "were" for the indicative singular.

Comment: @Rare "will" is incorrect in your second sentence. "Will" is used for something we are sure about. It doesn't make sense to combine it with a conditional or hypothetical construction. It could be: "If Robert wasn't so lazy he **would** be promoted." (Australian grammar, acceptable in many other variants). Use "If Robert **weren't** ..." for "Standard" grammar.

Answer (score 2):

If he would **had** told me is considered grammatically incorrect. The first example you showed is right.

Answer (score 2):

First example:

✔ Correct

Second example:

✖ Incorrect

Either having **had** without **would**, or having **have** with **would** are both correct,

Can't mix those to up!